# ST-Link clones not working, options?

Tags: stm32, st-link

Clone ST-Links have flooded the market everywhere. I have 4 of these laying around and 2 are dead. A very common problem is not being able to connect to the target mcu through swd using whatever methods like stm32cube programmer, third-party IDEs like visualgdb, Arduino IDE etc. It connects sporadically maybe after trying 10-20 times. There are many theories floating around like the reset pin not really working as intended. But it is a pain to work with nonetheless. I have to re insert the USB connector every time making the USB socket worn out.

Another problem is that they are hazardous in general. When the first one in my possession died, there was a lot of heat coming from it and last night when working with the second one, I got a notification in windows 11 that the usb device is trying to draw more power than my laptop can deliver. So it's shorted and stopped working since.

I am asking to the embedded community what they are doing about it. I have no problem buying an original ST-Link but they are nowhere to be found. Even the ones listed as original are overpriced clones.

For reference, I am talking about these:
[image]

UPDATE: I ended up buying an original looking one from Digi Key following one of the suggestions. Turned out those are fakes as well. Doesn't show a proper serial number in stm32cube programmer, let alone connect to target MCU. Digi Key is the only seller listed in st's website. This is a serious problem.

Comment: Why you are asking what we can do about it? You can choose to ignore that these pieces of garbage exist and do absolutely nothing about it. As with all things, buy official products from official sources. If something looks too good to be true, it likely is.

Comment: @Justme the problem is I can't find an original ST-Link no matter how much I search. I bought one from Amazon that was listed as original at a higher price but that turned out to be a clone as well.

Comment: Don't buy from Amazon where anyone can sell anything with any claims. Buy from a reputable source or directly from manufacturer web page.

Comment: @RajatMondal you must not be very good at finding things then ;) st.com, the website of the company that builds STLink debuggers, as well as the microcontrollers to use them with, **big** menu at top, select "Tools & Software", select "Development Tools", select "Hardware Debugger and Programmer Tools for STM32", select "Product Selector". There's the stlink/V2, which you can buy from 3 distributors. There's [more sources](https://octopart.com/st-link%2Fv2-stmicroelectronics-20057793?r=sp) as well.

Comment: The reset pin on such clones is for STM8 only and does not work in STM32 SWD mode at all. Anyway, it is important only if the STM32 firmware uses sleep mode with clock off or disables SWD lines by changing GPIO mode. In other cases such clones work IF they are not damaged (bad soldering, unwashed flux, etc, etc, etc)

Comment: @Justme thank you digi-key seems to have those in stock. I don't think I need a gst number to buy from them.

Comment: The clones also have supply pin outputs. And they only work with 3.3V IO levels. They can't power a large target board consuming an arbitrarily high amount of current, and if the target board is externally powered, the supplies must not be short circuited together, and the clone adapter or target board may get damaged if one of them is unpowered and current flows via programming pins. We can't know how you wire these things together and if that is the correct or incorrect way to wire them.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I bought a new one from a listed seller in my country: Digi-Key. Those are clones as well and doesn't work.

Comment: Digikey die you a cline ?!?! As an st product ?!?!

Comment: @MarcusMüller yep. Got it this morning. Now when I try to use it, I am faced with this problem that doesn't seem to have much discussion on the internet: "UR connection mode is defined with the HWrst reset mode" https://www.stm32duino.com/viewtopic.php?t=1902

Comment: Give digikey a call. They will want to sort that out very quickly.

Comment: @MarcusMüller It is becoming very painful because I like the small form factor of the blackpill. I am trying to learn PID control and starting off with a self-balancing robot that doesn't need wifi else I would have chosen the esp32.

Comment: @MarcusMüller ok

Comment: You've been played a terrible hand if digikey sent you a clone and you should not accept it. Their whole business depends on them being a **reliable** distributor that sells you exactly what you ordered and not a cover. Call them.

Comment: @MarcusMüller No way I am accepting this. It wasn't cheap either. But the main concern that I raised here still stands. There are so many outwardly convincing clones flooding the market that you can't even tell which is which. The one I have came with a very convincing box just like the picture of originals on the website. I think this problem alone contributes to the bigger markets for other mcus like esp32. If every other st-link on the market wasn't a faulty clone, stm32 would be a viable option for students and hobbyists alike.

Comment: I assure you it is. stm32 is a much much bigger player in both markets.  It's unlikely that all comes fail with writing cables and a working board. You have two separate problems

Answer (score 3):

> I am asking to the embedded community what they are doing about it.

Obviously, don't use sub-par products to do our work.

Honestly, an STM32 nucleo or discovery board costs not much, even compared to a working clone, and it comes with an ST-designed, factory-tested and independently usable STlink on-board. Use that for your own boards.

Comment: I do have a nucleo board. I myself have an old question on how to make it work with my own bluepill/blackpill boards. Never gotten it to work. I can program the nucleo board using external ST-Link(same problem, works sporadically) but not the other way around.

Comment: I can say from personal experience that programming a bluepill with a Nucleo board works. Seeing that in your previous questions, you had problems with wires, I'll recommend you maybe need more reliable wiring.

Comment: @RajatMondal But in your other questions you got it working, after buying a USB cable for Nucleo and using short jumper wires that make proper contact? We can't see what you are doing incorrectly if it does not work for you.

Comment: @Justme I'll add a schematic in a moment. The other question was for the opposite, because I didn't have or found a mini-usb cable to connect to the nucleo board. That taught me how the on board debugger works in general and as I said it works apart from the common connection issues. Programming a blackpill board from the nucleo however, never worked. I tried doing it from available answers here. I will update a schematic on the wiring topology.

Comment: @Justme I tried with the wiring exactly as shown here: https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/arduino/stm32/bluepill/

Comment: what I meant is that your cables sound like you have very unreliable cables.

Comment: @MarcusMüller standard Dupont connector cables everyone uses. And you are right I almost forgot to mention it, I did end up soldering the wires straight to the ST-Link last time and that did the trick. Maybe I'll have to do it again.

Comment: "standard Dupont" is like my least favourite kind of cable, *exactly* because this kind of reliability issues, but you have no choice here. But really, these come in "really terrible" with bad springs and unreliable contacting to "quite OK for a couple hundred insertions".

Comment: @MarcusMüller it's a shame because I really like the power of stm32 boards in the very low profile package unlike Arduino and esp32 boards. But working with ST-Link is a nightmare. And you can tell. Click on the st-link tag, all questions are exactly this.

Comment: Please read the documentation of your exact Nucleo board how to use it as a debugger for other targets. The tutorial you link to might not reflect your exact scenario, for example the reset pin needs special handling with solder bridges to work properly.

Comment: I'll see if I can find a better solution to the cable problem. Meanwhile I found original ST-Links on digi key as @Justme suggested. I think that will solve this recurring problem.

Comment: @RajatMondal it really is not a nightmare, honestly. Compared to a lot of other microcontroller platforms, it's very mature, reliable and easy to work with… it's not the platform's fault that you're trying to make cheap clones work with bad cables. That's like being angry at Mercedes because your luxury car drives very badly, after you bought the most damaged, used tires you could find.

Comment: @RajatMondal People ask about ST-Link problems when they have problems. People don't ask about ST-Link if it works. That's why you only see questions about why it does not work. Either it is used incorrectly, or they try to use clones which means instructions of original ST-Links don't apply.

Comment: @MarcusMüller nope, esp32 is most convenient in the programming phase. You can use their programmer or ftdi but the usb works flawlessly. They also have the most neat and clean codebase that works with any IDE and I was pleasantly surprised to see how advanced it was (implements most of C++ STL and even ASIO!) Unlike stm32cube projects that rely on comments for reconfiguration(Yikes). The only drawbacks are power consumption and size (most boards doesn't fit a breadboard).so I avoid it for non-wifi projects.

Comment: @RajatMondal I think what is more or less convenient is a subjective question. The point I was making is that if your obstacle is using the worst possible clones, then *any* platform is problematic. And you can also program STM32s via UART, so that comparison also doesn't work.

Comment: And: "They also have the most neat and clean codebase that works with any IDE" Um. um. No. Seriously. No. There's worse embedded code bases; but ESP32 code still isn't "good C" as far as this software engineer is concerned.

Comment: Well it's neat and clean to me. It does need you to be very proficient with CMake though, as it depends entirely on that. Upside is that everything is clean, conventional and very standardised CMake project. The component structure actively discourages spaghetti-code and helpful for maintaining modern SOLID principles. The stm32cube projects on the other hand, lookes like spaghetti without any effort from the developer. On the actual problem, I agree that I should get an original, but I couldn't find one to begin with so I asked what others do. This is a problem I only have with this platform.

Comment: yeah, not a fan of cubehal myself! But as said, in theory and practice, (nearly) every ST eval board does function quite well as STLink, so I really can't blame the platform for having hard to obtain debuggers. It's really not the point – the fact you can't get yours to work probably really is specific to something you're doing (and my somewhat educated guess is it's cables. It's cables most of the times, and we already know that some of your cables are especially bad).

Comment: "it comes with an ST-designed, factory-tested and independently usable STlink on-board. "  I just decided to try out the ST ecosystem for a new prototype.  Bought a Nucleo and a STLINK-V3SET for $35 - for programming in the lab.  Both devices worked the first time, as advertised.  No complaints here.

Comment: I understand. I don't want to play the blame game either. I know why it is so - free market capitalism at work here, and I prefer that over monopoly. I just wanted to know how users circumvent it. And I got a good answer - buy originals from DigiKey. I have heard of them (really good tutorials from Shawn Hymel, one of their affiliates) but never bought from them and google shopping doesn't show them so never considered it. Overall posting a question here was productive for me.